# Big stack frame size after compilation with clang on osx which leads to stack overflow

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, stack-overflow, clang++

I have two similar recursive functions:

```
void dfs(const std::vector<std::vector<int64_t>>& tree, int64_t position) {
  for (int64_t to : tree[position]) {
    dfs(tree, to);
  }

  if (position % 2 == 1) {
    for (int64_t to : tree[position]) {
    }
  } else {
    for (int64_t to : tree[position]) {
    }
  }
}
```

And the same code without range for loop:

```
void dfs(const std::vector<std::vector<int64_t>>& tree, int64_t position) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < tree[position].size(); ++i) {
    int64_t to = tree[position][i];
    dfs(tree, to);
  }

  if (position % 2 == 1) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tree[position].size(); ++i) {
      int64_t to = tree[position][i];
    }
  } else {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tree[position].size(); ++i) {
      int64_t to = tree[position][i];
    }
  }
}
```

full code available [here](https://gist.github.com/tau0/3b958366ff05a08ea4c06a88756f9c0e).

Unfortunately **the first one is segfaulting**, but only on osx with clang (3.5, 3.8, 3.9). I checked a stack frame size using gdb:

```
Stack level 1, frame at 0x7fff5fbfebe0:
rip = 0x100000a8c in dfs(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> > > > const&, long long); saved rip = 0x100000a8c
called by frame at 0x7fff5fbfef00, caller of frame at 0x7fff5fbfe8c0
Arglist at 0x7fff5fbfebd0, args: 
Locals at 0x7fff5fbfebd0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fff5fbfebe0
Saved registers:
rbp at 0x7fff5fbfebd0, rip at 0x7fff5fbfebd8
```

And it looks like the frame size in the dfs for the first function is: `0x7fff5fbfef00 - 0x7fff5fbfebe0 = 0x320 = 800`
**Why the first code are using near 1kb for a stack frame? While the second code are using only: `0x7fff5fbff240 - 0x7fff5fbff140 = 0x100 = 256` bytes.**

```
Stack level 1, frame at 0x7fff5fbff140:
rip = 0x100000d4d in dfs(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> > > > const&, long long); saved rip = 0x100000d4d
called by frame at 0x7fff5fbff240, caller of frame at 0x7fff5fbff040
Arglist at 0x7fff5fbff130, args: 
Locals at 0x7fff5fbff130, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fff5fbff140
Saved registers:
rbp at 0x7fff5fbff130, rip at 0x7fff5fbff138
```

PS: compilation flags:
clang++ -O0 -std=c++11 ./file.cpp

PSS: I tried to minify the code as much as I can. For example if I remove one empty range for loop in one of the branches everything become normal again.

PSSS: If I compile with g++-5 the frame size in dfs is only 0x50 = 128 byte. Also on Linux everything looks good.

Comment: Side note: give better names to your variables.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub thanks, I've tried to fix them.

Comment: Great. What does `dfs` means btw?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Depth First Search.